# Can I add one more speaker to a Sonos home theater set with surrounds and sub?

Tags: smart-home, audio

I’ve a complete Sonos home theater set with Playbase + 2 sonos One (Stereo) + Sub.

Since my kitchen is connected with the living room and I use youtube on TV to listen to music, I would like to add a spaeker to the set that works in the kitchen.

It’s ok if this speaker is used also when I watch a movie, and I don’t need the sound so far.

So my question is: can I add an additional speaker to the theater set, or am I going to lose the stereo functionality with the 2 sonos ones, or just it’s not possible?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking about ... you say that you want to add a speaker in the kitchen and then you say that you want to add a speaker to the theatre set

Comment: @jsotola That's weird to hear, because I've asked the same question on the Sonos forum, and It was answered correctly: https://en.community.sonos.com/ask-a-question-228987/can-i-add-one-more-speaker-to-a-sonos-home-theater-set-with-surrounds-and-sub-6842426